# How to access a private method of a particular class from a private method of another class in jframes of java netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe

I am stuck at how should I access a private method in java netbeans from other class private method. I have tried making private method "public" by right clicking on the button & "going in customize code".  And then I called the class by creating an object in that second class private method. And then using that object to call first class private method. Can anyone help?

Comment: You can't call private method in another class. You will have to make it public (assuming there isn't inheritance or inner class involved).

Comment: How should I made it public I have tried making it public by going in customize code option but it is showing private. What else is required?

Comment: quick-quiz : what is the meaning of private?

Comment: So it can't be changed to public in jframes?

Comment: It is only accessible in that class

Comment: But there is one method that allow us to access private method of other class. that is,  using reflection API.

Comment: I am having trouble using it in jframes.